# PFQueryTableViewController infinite-scroll swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, infinite-scroll

So what I'm trying to achieve is basically to use `PFQueryTableViewController` with infinite scrolling. So far, I've set `paginationEnabled` to false because I want to hide the "Show more" cell that appears. And I have also set the amount of posts to be loaded each "page" to be 10.

```
self.paginationEnabled = false
self.objectsPerPage = 10
```

Now for the infinite scrolling. I have set up the following function

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y < (self.view.bounds.size.height)) {
        if !self.loading {
            self.loadNextPage()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when it reaches the end (the last database rows) it just keeps looping the previous tableView cells. I need a way to check if there are new database rows to fetch or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the way I did this was that I set paginationEnabled to true instead of false.

```
self.paginationEnabled = true
```

Then I followed up the the following function

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row + 1 > self.objects?.count {
        return 0
    }
    let height = super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    return height
}
```

What this does is that it checks for the "Load more" cell. If there are 10 objects then the 11th would be the "Load more" cell. Therefore `indexPath.row + 1`. It then sets its height to 0 which hides it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you an idea:

Your `objectsPerPag = 10`. But when you query you will query 11. If you actual query return 11 objects so this result mean that continue have another object. You will continue loadmore. And when you return you will remove last object of this result query and you will get 10 item as you want.

Hope my idea can help you!